# How to draw and identify uncolored ROC curves in plot?

Tags: r, plot

My code below to plot ROC curves for x,y and z individually works, but I want the ROC curves in one single plot. In addition, since the plot will be published in an uncolored journal, the readers should be able to identify them via different lines (dashed etc) or arrows showing the corresponding line.

Any advice?

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(55)
y <- rnorm(55)
z <- rnorm(55)

data <- data(x,y,z)
status <- c(rep(1,25),rep(0,30))

model1 <- glm(status ~  x, family = binomial(link="logit") )
model2 <- glm(status ~  y, family = binomial(link="logit") )
model3 <- glm(status ~  z, family = binomial(link="logit") )

install.packages("pROC")
library(pROC)

prob1 <- predict(model1,type=c("response"))
data$prob1 <- prob1
plot1 <- roc(status ~ prob1)

prob2 <- predict(model2,type=c("response"))
data$prob2 <- prob2
plot2 <- roc(status ~ prob2)
plot(plot2,type="b")

prob3 <- predict(model3,type=c("response"))
data$prob3 <- prob3
plot3 <- roc(status ~ prob3)
plot(plot3)
```

Comment: Have you tried line types (lty = solid, dashed, dotted, etc), widths (lwd) and grey scales?

Comment: @Calimo, yes I did try them and they work. However, ADD=T does not work. So, the code produces 3 plots while I want one